# jQuery 'deferred object/promises' Performance?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Does any one know of any significant performance penalties involved with using the new jQuery 'promises/deferred object' pattern over the old jQuery style ajax methods that had standard 'success' and 'error' callbacks?

I know that moving forward we don't have much option now because 'deferred' objects are built into the AJAX core now but just wondered if there was any measurable difference and if the new 'promises' design pattern was actually more efficient than just old school anonymous function callbacks?

Kind regards,
Mark

Answer (score 3):

There should be no difference. It's just syntactic sugar.

If you care about performance don't use the jQuery abstraction.

Create your own `XMLHttpRequest` object and handle it in pure JS.

**[Edit]**

To rephrase: There is a very minor performance penalty for the new deferred/promises wrapper because it has a couple more layers and functions to go through.

The performance difference is probably an order of magnitude lower then the performance difference for using jQuery for ajax instead of XMLHttpRequests.

Both of these differences are pretty neglible compared to the flexibility and cross browser compliance they offer you.

If they matter then put blunty your having far too many ajax requests going off.

Comment: Do you have any numbers backing up that using jquery for ajax calls is slow?  I'm not inclined to believe that it is significantly slower.

Comment: Compared with network latency you can ignore the minor performance penalties caused by a wrapper like jquery...

Comment: performance is no issue, it's cross browser compatibility that jQuery promises.

Comment: @xaxxon & others: Keep in mind the question that's being asked. OP is effectively asking about micro-optimizations. The answer seems appropriate to me. Don't sweat the difference, but if you're concerned about that level of optimization, then you'll gain more by removing the abstraction. I don't @Raynos is saying that the cost isn't worth the benefit in most cases.

Comment: @xaxxon It's not noticeably slower. I'm just saying that the difference between JS and jQuery vs jQuery and jQuery 1.5 is larger in terms of performance.

Comment: There seems a performance hit. I am using 6 synch blocking ajax calls to fetch some data to render a template. Total time for all the calls added is 122 ms but after using $.when().done(), the ajax fired simultaneously but individual request took time in order of 300-400ms, thus degrading performance which is more than total time time taken for all the sync ajax requests in order. I would advise to use this feature with care.

Comment: https://twitter.com/derickbailey/status/210860648924590080 somebody also twitted about the same.